# Narrow down type of field, based on another field

Tags: typescript

I have this interface:

```
enum CatEngine {
  Electric = "ev",
  Petrol = "petrol",
}

interface ElectricEngineDetails {
  range: number
}


interface PetrolEngineDetails {
  mpg: number
}

interface ICar {
  engine: CarEngine;
  details: ElectricEngineDetails | PetrolEngineDetails;
}
```

Is there a way to write a type guard that accepts an `engine` and a `details`, and returns the `details`, narrowed down to the corresponding `engine` type? I know it can be done in-place but I wish to extract it to a separate function.

Comment: You want a typeguard ? I'm not sure this can work unless you use litteral values as arguments of your typeguard

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `type` instead of an `interface` for `ICar`(or `Car` since it's not an interface anymore):

```
type Car = { engine: CarEngine.Electric; details: ElectricEngineDetails } | { engine: CarEngine.Petrol; details: PetrolEngineDetails };
```

or you could create interfaces for the types:

```
type Car = IElectricCar | IPetrolCar;

interface IElectricCar {
  engine: CarEngine.Electric;
  details: ElectricEngineDetails;
}

interface IPetrolCar {
  engine: CarEngine.Petrol;
  details: PetrolEngineDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a generic interface, something like this:

```
type ICar<T extends CarEngine> = {
  engine: T;
  details: T extends CarEngine.Electric ? ElectricEngineDetails : PetrolEngineDetails;
}
```

This will compute the type for `details` depending on the type of `engine`. You can use it like this:

```
const ev: ICar<CarEngine.Electric> = {
 engine: CarEngine.Electric,
 details: {
  range: 23,
 }
}
```

Trying to use `mpg` will result in an error, as TS knows that `details` are of type `ElectricEngineDetails`.

With this you can write up a type guard function that does the type narrowing:

```
const isElectric = (car: ICar<CarEngine.Electric> | ICar<CarEngine.Petrol>): car is ICar<CarEngine.Electric> => {
  if (car.engine === CarEngine.Electric) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
function something (car: ICar<CarEngine.Petrol> | ICar<CarEngine.Electric>): void {
   if (isElectric(car)) {
     car.details.range;
   } else {
     car.details.mpg;
   }
}
```

Here's a full example on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=40&ssc=2&pln=34&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgJwKIgOYEsTCgbwFBRRIA2wAxgC4LplQC8UARMAG6MA0BUACsFQPbF6TAA58EgjngC+ePJgrAEAMzhlsJclRooMWACJ846YgGdcXBHDTAAXFHAQARkplyFS1ep7jBuzMCGFMZmFoQQIqj2ji4IbngUAJ5iUACS8AgAPAAqUMAAHoogACbmGf5YAHzC+ISgenZQ2QDcXMVGJqb2uQVFpbCIFcAAdJqU1LQA-ESk4zpoAUEh5va8AsRDS52tsnhk-CCmFHmz2mT26YiZ5QtYo6cT1Qy1ebeNNw33WhOchO3BnXsL0IVhs9gATABmX5QWS7faHY7oUxjM7CAAUZEQFwy10Gby+czI1QAPmlcR8AsM1hJiJUAJT2LEIKDI8lXSl3VGPejVF7oZRQTGIYb1AL0OgMTkjbk0elhQhQBB8MAIEBQKhgYCtQi7EEqtVQVRmbXxZRgECUdAHKCmfgQPgAC0wqCFzJxHPxnxpglJ7Ky0sJZwZ9hY-HQxQVrMF6ORsrIwoQ9PlwMIzOG-2Ww1BqFNiukJ1M2FTUHTmc6wwiqB1upkQA).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions)

Basically, you need to define an union that is composed of all the possibilities, **but** all your interfaces must have a common and discriminant property that will allow Typescript to know how to eliminate types conditionally

You can test it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgJwKIgOYEsTCgbwFBRRIA2wAxgC4LplQC8UARMAG6MA0BUACsFQPbF6TAA58EgjngC+ePJgrAEAMzhlsJclRooMWACJ846YgGdcXBHDTAAXFHAQARkplz5IRSrXZeA4rqYwIYUxmYWhBAiqPaOLghueAD0SVD66KZk1BCY1hRQYCDo-CB4FACeYrCIwgCSmpTUZPAIUAA+ULV+EsQtANxyCkqq6p0N2s01+ISgenbVyGhBAHTjTQOEACZGJqb2azpLBjtmA7IeXiPYXeKCLRFQs0H2LYFYy92CG1Dbobv2nwCR2CJ1MZzk2zIxEQ2DIJVM+TIiBeiEGyigAAokQhlk8sPQ6AxXsDVqRGjQAJQPbHLX5hUzLKw2KApKD8ADWXBpdN2yyiqBZqX0-GAphAAHJ8sAAB4ZCgyR5mbDTQVQABKwAg-BYwE2YzJE3uygk0AoAAtsIViiAoC4kWBTNgACqVUVZdAifLskD8ADuUBpeNh1i4rJ9+RcCzewFJWiaUGs5S1CGA7Cgpn4bJAxHKnUB9wyCZYYTgTlIUEwUHNlqKJS5iFpoL50VVHPrOJ5ZkZ1lQ2FZwtFEqlsoRMiAA)

```ts
enum CarEngine {
  Electric = "ev",
  Petrol = "petrol",
}

interface ElectricEngineDetails {
  range: number
}


interface PetrolEngineDetails {
  mpg: number
}

// Discriminant union, engine will be the discriminant property
type Car = IElectricCar | IPetrolCar;

interface IElectricCar {
  // Electric car will have 'ev' as a type for engine
  engine: CarEngine.Electric;
  details: ElectricEngineDetails;
}

interface IPetrolCar {
  // Petrol car will have 'petrol' as a type for engine
  engine: CarEngine.Petrol;
  details: PetrolEngineDetails;
}

declare const car: Car

// car types are discriminated based on the `engine` property
if (car.engine === CarEngine.Electric) {
  car.details.range // ok
  car.details.mpg // Doesn't exist
} else {
  // Removed IElectricCar from the union because Typescript know car.engine can
  // not be CarEngine.Electric anymore, so only IPetrolCar is available in the union
  car.details.mpg // ok
  car.details.range // Doesn't exist
}
```